# How to redirect to home page after clicking browser back button, when on a particular page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am creating a flight booking website using the MERN stack. The final confirmation page shows a receipt and flight ticket. I want to redirect the user to the home page on clicking the back button, while on the confirmation page. I am using react-router-dom.

Comment: Quick questions:
1. is the back button is in your UI or you are talking about the browser back button?
2. Are using any kind of routing API in your project, react-router-dom or reach-router or anything else

Comment: Talking about the browser back button. I am using react-router-dom.

Comment: Browser Back button looks for a history stack maintained by the browser itself, Its not possible to override the action on that button.

Comment: What you can do if it is necessary, that you tell every route component of yours to check if this route is loaded by redirecting from the confirmation page, then redirect to home instead of rendering the route.
Example:
if you have 7 routes in the application, each pointing to a route/screen/page. You have to write a if condition in the render function to see, if its browser.history has a entry of the conformation page on top. then redirect to '/home'.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example, and details about what is or isn't working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: **You can't change the behavior of the Browser Back Button.**

Long answer:

> Browser Back button looks for a history stack maintained by the browser itself, Its not possible to override the action on that button.

Workaround:

What of we tell each of your route components(components/screen/page attached with to the path) to check if the last location visited in the application is `/confirmation-page` then redirect to `/home`.

***But it won't be a good practice!***